# Installation of python packages from terminal started to fail, Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, flask, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was not able to solve this for days, so if you can give me any advice I would appreciate it!

When I try to install any package from python I get this message (in this case lets take flask for example):

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/flask/
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for Flask "

I do not really understand what caused it because previously everything worked well and I was able to install packages. And, I did not install anything new in between. Also, I am really a beginner in python programming and I do not fully understand what exactly the message is trying to say. I definitely have an internet connection and I have installed e.g. Flask previously and have used it as well. The only thing that happened before everything got stack was that my internet provider has "rebooted" my internet connection (I am not sure that "reboot" is the right termini for that).

I am using Windows subsystem for Linux, Visual studio code and python version: Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) [GCC 8.3.0] on Linux.

Comment: How are you trying to install? What's the command you're entering?

Comment: I was using this pip3 install -r requirements.txt --user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a DNS issue. Pip would be trying to resolve https://pypi.org. But ultimately that has to resolve to an IP Address.

Most ISPs provide a DNS service by default. Perhaps it wasn't able to resolve it?

When you added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` you're using a Google DNS server which, it seems worked as expected by resolving https://pypi.org

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding: 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
to the file:
/etc/resolv.conf 
(via $sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf and save)
BUT I still do not understand fully why it worked? and Where came the problem from?